# Prestashop - Get category ID - product-json.tpl (schema.org template)

Tags: schema, prestashop

How can I get category ID in schema.org template? {$id_category} doesen't work...  I need category id for implementings products on facebook. Without category id, facebook won't retrieve products... Please help

```
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "{$product.name}",
    "description": "{$page.meta.description|regex_replace:"/[\r\n]/" : " "}",
    "category": "{$id_category}",
    {if !empty($product.cover)}"image" :"{$product.cover.bySize.home_default.url}",{/if}
    "sku": "{if $product.reference}{$product.reference}{else}{$product.id}{/if}",
    "mpn": "{if $product.mpn}{$product.mpn}{elseif $product.reference}{$product.reference}{else}{$product.id}{/if}"
    {if $product.ean13},"gtin13": "{$product.ean13}"
    {else if $product.upc},"gtin13": "{$product.upc}"
    {/if}
    {if $product_manufacturer->name OR $shop.name},
    "brand": {
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "{if $product_manufacturer->name}{$product_manufacturer->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$shop.name}{/if}"
    }
```

{$id_category} shows nothing